# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null when i run got this error

Tags: javascript

i tried this code  but when i run the code this problem exist
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null  when i run got this error

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <input class="btns" type="submit" placeholder="submittt" />
 <script src="index.js"></script>
 </body>
  </html>
```

and in index.js

```
var l = document.querySelector("btns");
    l.addEventListener("click", myfunction);
myfunction();
    {
    var k = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    alert(k);
     };
```

Comment: Since querySelector catch match multiple selectors, so you need to specify that btns is a class `".btns"` by prefixing it with a `.`. Also, you should double-check your function declaration (no `function` keyword and you also don't need `;` after it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call the function inside the eventlistener function:

You need to use the `.` to get element which has class.

```js
var l = document.querySelector(".btns")
l.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert();
});

function alert(){
    var k = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    alert(k);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input class="btns" type="submit" placeholder="submittt" />
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `.` in your class name when using `querySelector`.

Update the line to `var l = document.querySelector(".btns");`

Also, you will need to change `myfunction();` to `function myfunction()`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the definition of querySelector at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

querySelector uses CSS selectors so by asking it to find the first element with selector 'btns' you are asking it to find the first element with tag btns in the DOM. It can't find one so returns null.

To get it to find the first element with class="btns" you need to use the same syntax as you would in the CSS stylesheet: '.btns'

Answer (score 0):

There was 2 issue in your code

1. The `querySelector` parameter was not correct
2. The click handler not properly written

Please find below code which depicts what you trying to achieve.

```js
const l = document.querySelector(".btns");

l.addEventListener("click", myfunction);
function myfunction() {
    var k = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    alert(k);
};
```

```html
<input class="btns" type="submit" placeholder="submittt"  value="submit"/>
```